# Sorting Pandas Dataframe by matching multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this:

```
data=np.array([[-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05]])

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['x','y','z'])
```

and a numpy array

```
coord=np.array([[-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05]])
```

The number of rows in the Pandas Dataframe and the coord array are always the same. As you can see, the rows between the Pandas DataFrame and the coord are the same but in a different order. I would like to sort the DataFrame according to the order of the coord array(e.g. df.x==coord[:,0] & df.y==coord[:,1] & df.z==coord[:,2]).

Comment: What happens if you have duplicates coordinates?

Comment: I am not sure how that would work. But most of the immediate dataset I am dealing with, the coordinates are all unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it like this:

- sort both arrays the same way
- set the index of the dataframe to that of coord
- reset the index to get the original ordering:

code

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(coord, columns=list("xyz"))
sort_cols = list("yxz")
df = df.sort_values(sort_cols)
df2 = df2.sort_values(sort_cols)
df.index = df2.index
df = df.sort_index()
```

This should returns the df sorted as coord (output):

```
          x         y         z
0 -0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000047
1 -0.000016  0.000016 -0.000047
2  0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000047
3  0.000016  0.000016 -0.000047
4 -0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000016
5 -0.000016  0.000016 -0.000016
6  0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000016
7  0.000016  0.000016 -0.000016
```

Comment: I should say: it would obviously be easier to just construct the dataframe from the coord.  If this is possible for your problem it would be easier/more performant

Comment: Yes, I agree! Especially for some of the dataset I am processing can have up to millions of rows. The problem I have is the DataFrame and coord array is generated by two different softwares. I just figured out that the coord array is sorted by z, x, y in ascending order. The issue now is I am uncertain if this would always be true.

Comment: hm... you may be better off just sorting *all* data (including numpy) by x,y,z rather than doing index matching.  I think this along the lines of the other response

Answer (score 0):

You can do the required sorting by:

```
df.sort_values(['x', 'y', 'z'], ascending=[True, True, True])
```

The full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=np.array([[-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05],
[1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05],
[1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-1.5625e-05]])

df= pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['x','y','z'])

df.sort_values(['x', 'y', 'z'], ascending=[True, True, True])

print(df)
```

the output:

```
          x         y         z
0 -0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000047
1 -0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000016
2 -0.000016  0.000016 -0.000047
3 -0.000016  0.000016 -0.000016
4  0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000047
5  0.000016 -0.000016 -0.000016
6  0.000016  0.000016 -0.000047
7  0.000016  0.000016 -0.000016
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it. It didn't work. The main issue is the coord array is generated randomly and does not follow any pattern.

Comment: I examined it with your array and it succeeded.

Comment: The first row of the sorted DataFrame matches, but the second row does not : [-0.000016, -0.000016, -0.000016] vs [-1.5625e-05,1.5625e-05,-4.6875e-05]

Comment: first, it sort based on x, and if x is repeated, it sort accoring to y, and if y is repeated it sort accoring to z and (-0.000047 < -0.000016) when comparing row1 and row2

Comment: I just check again based on your last comment. Your answer was almost there. If you change the order of sorting to df.sort_values(['z', 'x', 'y'], ascending=[True, True, True]), then the answer would match. Again, my issue is that I cannot guarantee the coord array generated to be pre-sorted in this exact order (z,x,y). Thank you for your help!